# Data mine a huge amount of data

Tags: reporting, data-mining, business-intelligence

I store a huge amount of reporting elements in a MySQL database. These elements are stored in a simple way :

```
KindOfEvent;FromCountry;FromGroupOfUser;FromUser;CreationDate
```

All these reporting elements should permit to display graphs from different points of view. I have tried using SQL requests for that but it is very slow for users. As this graph will be used by non-technical users, I need a tool to pre-work the result.
I am very new to all this data-mining, reporting, olap concepts. If you know a pragmatic approach not so time consuming, or a tool for that, it would help !

Comment: Well, so far you have not mentioned any data-mining yet, just that you are querying a database with SQL and that is too slow for you...

Comment: What do you mean by huge amount? And by graphs, do you mean charts/diagrams?

Comment: Sorry for the bad wording. I meant charts and diagrams and also "tools". I am now looking at hadoop

Comment: Could you give us more details about what you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could setup [OLAP cubes](http://www.iccube.com/solutions/overview) on top of your MySQL data. The multi-dimensional model will help your users navigating through and analysing the data either via Excel or Web dashboards. One thing specific to icCube is its ability to integrate any Javascript charting library and to embed the dashboard within your own pages.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with DB, but I think MySQL is far than enough for your problems. Well designed index or transaction will speed up the query process.

Answer (score -1):

I am not a DB expert but if you want to process graphs, you can use Neo4J (java graph processing framework), or SNAP (C++ graph processing framework), or employee cloud computing if this is possible. I would recommend either Hadoop (MapReduce) or Giraph (cloud graph processing). For graph display you can use whatever tools suites you. Of course "the best" technology depends on the data size. If none of the above suites you, try finding something that does on the wiki page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database

InforGrid (http://infogrid.org/trac/) looks like might suite you.